# inApp purchase multiple device for same user

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I integrated **inApp purchase** in the app to unlock other content using server model i.e i sent a receipt data to the server for validation.

**Problem** : If user has multiple devices suppose Device1 and Device2

1. Device1: user installs XYZ app, registers itself with mailed/password and then subscribed the content.
2. Device2: (same user) user installs XYZ app, registers itself with mailed/password and go to subscription page.

**Question** : How can I came to know that this Device2 belongs to the same user who already subscribed from Device1?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]
```

Read more about restoring transactions in Apple documentation:

[StoreKit Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW2)

[SKPaymentQueue reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008257-CH1-SW14)

Answer (score 0):

Have the user log in to the iTunes Store using the same account from both devices. When they attempt to download your IAP it will be seen as a redownload and they won't be charged.

Comment: yes, both devices has same account. But apple guys are saying, you provide some mechanism to get user know.

Comment: Isn't there an API function that allows you to check for a receipt? If so, use that at launch to see if the user has already bought your IAP, and if so, present them with a prompt to authorize the new device?